# How to binding list in list to Datagrid WPF

Tags: wpf, listview, datagrid

I have class a BangLuong.cs

```
public partial class BangLuong
{
    public BangLuong()
    {
        this.LuongThuongs = new HashSet<LuongThuong>();
    }

    public int MaBangLuong { get; set; }
    public int MaNV { get; set; }
    public Nullable<decimal> TienLuong { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> Thang { get; set; }
    public string DonVi { get; set; }

    public virtual NhanVien NhanVien { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<LuongThuong> LuongThuongs { get; set; }
}
```

And I want to binding `List<BangLuong>` to `DataGrid`. A `BangLuong` have list `LuongThuongs`
When user click row in datagrid, it show list `LuongThuongs` match this `BangLuong`
I try binding in xaml:

```
 <DataGrid Grid.Row="2" ItemsSource="{Binding ListEntities, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Style="{StaticResource DataGridStyle}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay}">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Binding="{Binding IsChecked, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" IsReadOnly="False">
                <DataGridCheckBoxColumn.HeaderTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <CheckBox Command="{Binding SalaryDialog.CheckAllCommand}" DataContext="{StaticResource Locator}" CommandParameter="{Binding IsChecked, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridCheckBoxColumn.HeaderTemplate>
            </DataGridCheckBoxColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Mã bảng lương" Binding="{Binding MaBangLuong}" Width="Auto" IsReadOnly="True"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Tiền lương" Binding="{Binding TienLuong}" Width="Auto" IsReadOnly="True"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Tháng" Binding="{Binding Thang, Converter={StaticResource ConvertDataTimeToDateString}}" Width="Auto" IsReadOnly="True"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Trợ cấp" Binding="{Binding TroCap}" Width="*" IsReadOnly="True"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Đơn vị" Binding="{Binding DonVi}" Width="Auto" IsReadOnly="True"/>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Chức năng" Width="Auto">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Button Content="Xóa" Command="{Binding SalaryDialog.DeleteCommand}" DataContext="{StaticResource Locator}" CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedItem, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=DataGrid}}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding LuongThuongs}">
                    <GridView>
                        <GridView.Columns>
                            <GridViewColumn Header="Loại lương thưởng" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding LoaiLuongThuong.TenLoaiLuong}" />
                            <GridViewColumn Header="Số tiền" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding SoTien}" />
                        </GridView.Columns>
                    </GridView>
                </ListView>
            </DataTemplate>
        </DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
    </DataGrid>
```

It throw exception of Xaml. How to do that?
Exception: XamlParseException occurred
Message: Operation is not valid while ItemsSource is in use. Access and modify elements with ItemsControl.ItemsSource instead.

Comment: what is the exception that you are getting?

Comment: see my update above @nit